# I want to use cin after read input with istream operator

Tags: c++, cin, istream-iterator

I use istream_iterator to read integers from input (until eof) and store them to a vector

after that i want to read a single integer (or maybe a value of another type e.g. string). How can i do that?

- Should i use cin (maybe "clear" it somehow)? 
  should i use the already istream_iterator created?

the "problematic" code is the following. It does not read the value with cin.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
// creates two iterators to the begin end end of std input
istream_iterator<int> int_it(cin), eof;

vector<int> int_vec(int_it,eof);


// prints the vector using iterators
cout<<"You gave me the vector: ";
copy(int_vec.begin(),int_vec.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
cout<<endl;

int value;
cout<<"Give me the value you want to search for: ";
cin>>value;

int x=count(int_vec.begin(),int_vec.end(),value);
cout<<"Value "<<value<<" is found "<<x<<" times\n";
}
```

Comment: You want to read several integers, followed by an integer? How will you know when to stop?

Comment: Yes, maybe you *could* [clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) it somehow?

Comment: [Beta] I want to read vector integers until the user press ctrl-D (eof). Then i want to re-user the cin for reading other stuff.
[Some programmer dude] I tried cin.clear() before cin but nothing changed

Comment: Ctrl-D closes stdin, so you would have to reopen it. It may be easier to user another way to terminate the list. Maybe use -1 to indicate the list? Or an empty string? Or an explicit string like "end" or "quit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you wrote:

> I want to read vector integers until the user press ctrl-D (eof). Then i want to re-user the cin for reading other stuff.

You cannot do that. Once `std::cin`/`stdin` is closed it cannot be reopened for reading more data from it.

You can use a different strategy though. Instead of relying on EOF to detect the end of input for the vector of integers, you can use something that is not an integer. For example, if your input consists of

```
1 2 3 4 end
```

then the reading to `int_vec` will stop at the start of the "end" in the input stream. Then, you can use `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` to clear the error state of the stream and discard the rest of the input in the line before continuing to read more from `cin`.

#### Updated version of your program

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // creates two iterators to the begin end end of std input
   cout << "Input some integers. Enter something else to stop.\n";
   istream_iterator<int> int_it(cin), eof;
   vector<int> int_vec(int_it, eof);

   // prints the vector using iterators
   cout<<"You gave me the vector: ";
   copy(int_vec.begin(),int_vec.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
   cout << endl;

   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

   int value = 0;
   cout << "Give me the value you want to search for: ";
   cin >> value;

   int x = count(int_vec.begin(), int_vec.end(), value);
   cout << "Value " << value << " is found " << x << " times\n";
}
```

#### Console Input and Output

```
Input some integers. Enter something else to stop.
1 2 3 4 end
You gave me the vector: 1 2 3 4
Give me the value you want to search for: 1
Value 1 is found 1 times
```